# Why f(1)=1 for every multiplicative function f?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, multiplicative-function

If $f$ is a multiplicative function with $f(1)\ne0$, then why is $f(1)$ necessarily equal to $1$?

Comment: just multiply :-)

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Considers what happens to $f(1)f(1)$.

Comment: $f(1)=f(1)*f(1)$

If we let $f(1)=n$, then $f(1)=n^2$. And if we keep going $f(1)=n^n$  Is this correct so far?

Comment: The first part is right. Write $f(1) = a$. You have $a = a^2$. What can you conclude about $a$ from this?

Comment: $a^2-a=0$ or $(a(a-1))=0$ Therefore either $a=0$ or $a=1$?

Comment: You got it. Now what does that tell you about $f(1)$?

Comment: f(1)=a=0 or f(1)=a=1. But since f(1) is not zero, it is 1!

Comment: Exactly right :)

Answer (score 0):

Since we know $f$ is multiplicative, then $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$.

So $f(1\cdot a)= f(a) =f(1)f(a)$.

This is only true when $f$ is zero everywhere, or $f(1)=1$.

Comment: Be careful, this is valid only if $\gcd(a, b)=1$